# Search two columns and echo results for a range

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form **textfield** and **submit**. When a number is entered say 102 and submitted, it searches the db and looks at two columns (smin & smax).  The number typed in the textbox will be in one of 10 ranges.  It will then find the range it equals to (102 would be in the 3rd range - **look below**) and then echo info for that range.

DB Table

```
id  smin  smax
1   50    80
2   81    95
3   96    103
```

etc

I just can't wrap my head around on what to do.  The reason, I have over 10 ranges and then to tell it to echo some text about the range is something I've never done.

```
$stmt= $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE 
smin >=100 AND smax <= 119');
```

Of course this doesn't work and not what I want to do since I have db ... I want it to go to the db and search those two columns and determine which row it's equal to.

Comment: there are much better table structures for this

Comment: let me guess, you are actually saving your data like `50 - 81 - 96 ...`, that, in one column. If so, the Architect was in a coma that day

Comment: No guys the db is fine. I didn't know how else to do it with this editor.  Please answer the question if you know.  If you don't no problem..

Comment: Thanks Drew. I appreciate it.

Comment: ok, you have user data, let's say it is nnn.  You do a prepare (ignore the lack of ? or :theNumber for now). But it is nnn. So it is `select * from ranges where smin<=nnn and smax>=nnn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DB setup:

```
create table ranges
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    smin int not null,
    smax int not null
);
insert ranges (smin,smax) values (32,49),(50,80),(81,95),(96,103),(104,115); -- etc
```

### PDO with Prepare and Bind

The question was tagged `pdo`

```
<?php
    $theNum=102;    // get from user, this is hard-coded
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=so_gibberish;charset=utf8', 'TheUser', 'ThePassword');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,smin,smax from ranges 
            WHERE smin <= :theNum AND smax >= :theNum');
        $stmt->bindParam(':theNum', $theNum, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // one row we hope
            $data = "id: ".$row['id'] . ", smin: " . $row['smin'] . ", smax: " . $row['smax'] . "\n";
            print $data;
        }
        $stmt = null;
        // PDO closes connection at end of script

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

### Output:

id: 4, smin: 96, smax: 103

Comment: Thank You for being so detailed.  I learned a lot due to your answer.   Thanks.

Comment: my pleasure, sorry I shoved 102 into the 4th range !

Answer (score 2):

Let's say AJAX sends the value entered to the Server. Then it would be like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['HTMLnameAttribute'])){
  $numVal = $_POST['HTMLnameAttribute'];
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE smin >= $numuVal && smax <= $numVal");
  $stmt->execute();
  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($r = $stmt->fetchObject()){
      // $r is Object - access like $r->id; $r->smin; $r->smax;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

The code above assumes that you have database connection already.